# How to get the sum of a slice of an n-dimensional array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have an n-dimensional array in NumPy. I would like to calculate the sum of all the elements in a slice. For instance:

if I have the following 2x2x2 3D array having the values:

```
z = 1
1 2
3 4

z = 2
5 6
7 8
```

When I get a slice for z = 1 I would like to get 10 and for z = 2 I would like to get 26.

I can use the following for a 3D space but how can I do that for n dimensional space?

```
(array.sum(axis = 0)).sum(axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum the `i`th slice along the `d`th dimension: `arr.take([i], axis=d).sum()`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are over complicating this:

```
>>> a=(np.arange(8)+1).reshape(2,2,2)
>>> a
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
>>> np.sum(a[0])
10
>>> np.sum(a[1])
26
>>> a[:,0]
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
>>> np.sum(a[:,0])
14
```